# MAUI share storage between multiple apps

Tags: .net-core, maui

I have a requirement for 2 MAUI apps to share certain data on the local device.
I'm sure I've read somewhere that the same software vendor can make their apps share locally stored data. I cant seem to find it now.

My scenario is I want to share connection details between apps so I don't have to make users fill in the same details twice.

Is this possible?

Comment: Which platform did you target? There is no api in the maui can do that. You need to call the platform native code.

Comment: Im targeting both android and IOS, could you point me in the right direction for what I need to read up on. Im familiar with using the native code, I'm just not sure what the features are I need to research

Comment: For the ios you can check this link about [[iOS] Shared Resources for two Apps from the same developer](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/84189).